# Is there any difference between these two index creation modes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's just a simple question that could be answered in comments. Is there any difference between these two definitions:

```
CREATE INDEX ON sample ((column1 = true), (column2 = true));

CREATE INDEX ON sample ((column1 = true AND column2 = true));
```

Suppose both columns will be used with AND condition ever. Will the second has more advantage when using on queries like `SELECT column3 FROM sample WHERE column1 = true AND column2 = true;` or they will be the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Although I am using PostgreSQL I was asking from a general point of view, but why? Some databases handle the same index creation differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  The first creates an index with two keys, each of which can take on 2 (or 3 if you count `NULL`) values.  The second creates an index on one key, which can take on 2 (or 3) values.

Both can be used for the query you have in mind.  However, only the first could be used for:

```
where column1 = true
```

In general, indexes are most useful when they are selective.  If the conditions apply equally to the data, then the index would return about 25% of the rows -- that is still a bunch of rows and the index may not be useful.